# Let n be a nonzero integer and p an odd prime not dividing n.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

$p/(x^2+ny^2)$ for $x$, $y$ relatively prime $\Leftrightarrow$ to $(\frac{-n}{p})=1$.

I have proved the "$\Rightarrow$" part by using the fact that $y$ and $p$ must be relatively prime, which implies that there exist $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\alpha y+\beta p=1$ and so $\alpha=y^{-1}$ (mod $p$). Then $-n=(xy^{-1})^2$ (mod $p$). So, since $p$ does not divide $-n$, $-n$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$.

I am not sure about the "$\Leftarrow$" part of the proof. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Consider a solution to $x^2 \equiv -n \pmod{p}$. Since $-n$ is a quadratic residue by assumption, that exists.

Comment: Ok, so I have already thought of something like this.

Since -n is a quadratic residue mod p, then we can write $-n=q^2+pz$, for some integer $z$. Then we get $q^2+n*1^2=0$ (mod $p$) with $gcd(q,1)=1$. 

From this we can also deduce
$q^2+n*(1+a_1*p+a_2*p^2+\dots+a_k*p^k)=0$ (mod $p$),
so $x=q$ and $y^2=1+a_1*p+a_2*p^2+\dots+a_k*p^k$. We know that $y^2=1$ (mod $p$) always has a solution. But how do I know for sure that x and y taken this way are coprime? (Sorry if this is really obvious...)

Comment: Just settle for a particular $y$. $y = 1$ is a good choice.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! I actually understood the question wrong. I thought they wanted that to be true for any ($x$, $y$) coprime.

Comment: I see. It wouldn't be true for _all_ coprime $(x,y)$.